# JQwidget combo box: Unselect Item not working

Tags: jqwidget

I'm using JQwidget combo box with multi select. For each selection, I'm doing some validation and if validation fails, I'm trying to remove the selected item from the combo box. I use the below code to achieve this but it doesn't seems to work. Also it look like the on un selecting, the select event is getting fired unnecessarily. Please let me know what's wrong here.

```
$("#jqxCombo").on('select', function (event) {  
                var args = event.args;
                var item = args.item;
                $("#jqxCombo").jqxComboBox('unselectItem', item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the provided code which uses the jQWidgets ComboBox. There is a missing $ symbol after var items =. Please, take a look at this sample: https://www.jseditor.io/?key=d22d2e14161211e8a2dc00224d6bfcd5 which you can use as a solution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using the same approach here but with a multi select and it seems on un select, the select event is getting fired again. Can you help please.